# MS Access Combox gets all values instead of one value

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox, ms-access-2013

in MS Access 2013, I have a combobox with these proporties:

[image]

It Has 7 values from the Currency table.

when I compile or run the project, if I choose the first record from the combo, debug shows that I have chosen all of them. the problem occurs only for the first record of combo, all goes ok i f I choose another record. any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe look at Me.Iso.SelectedItem?  Actually, what seems odd is that USD is replaced by CHF at the bottom of the list.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Its  a strange USD dissapeared too. but if I choose USD from combo, everything works perfect.
this combobox has not SelectedItem property, only has Selected property which gives me an error ""argument not optional"